# Valid Topojson and https://mapshaper.org/

Tags: topojson

All 3 cases validate in jsonlint, but only the first one is displayed in mapshaper.

I do not understand why case 2 and 3 are not displayed .

So how can I set up this correct using '-' in the arcs ref for a property ?

1. Displays OK in https://mapshaper.org/

```
    {"type":"Topology", "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:25832"}},"objects":{"collection": { "type": "GeometryCollection", "geometries":[
    { "type": "MultiPolygon", "arcs": [[[0,1]]],"properties":{"id":9005309}}]}},"arcs": 
    [
    [[565546,7786890.97],[565545.69,7786859.81]],
    [[565545.69,7786859.81],[565545.06,7786876.95],[565546,7786890.97]]]
    }
```

2. Does not displays in https://mapshaper.org/

```
    {"type":"Topology", "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:25832"}},"objects":{"collection": { "type": "GeometryCollection", "geometries":[
    { "type": "MultiPolygon", "arcs": [[[-0,-1]]],"properties":{"id":9005309}}]}},"arcs":
    [
    [[565545.69,7786859.81],[565546,7786890.97]],
    [[565546,7786890.97],[565545.06,7786876.95],[565545.69,7786859.81]]
    ]
    }
```

3. Does not displays in https://mapshaper.org/

```
    {"type":"Topology", "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:25832"}},"objects":{"collection": { "type": "GeometryCollection", "geometries":[
    { "type": "MultiPolygon", "arcs": [[[-0,1]]],"properties":{"id":9005309}}]}},"arcs": 
    [
    [[565545.69,7786859.81],[565546,7786890.97]],
    [[565545.69,7786859.81],[565545.06,7786876.95],[565546,7786890.97]]]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong index for negative (/reversed) arcs:

> Each arc must be referenced by numeric zero-based index into the
> containing topology’s arcs array. For example, 0 refers to the first
> arc, 1 refers to the second arc, and so on.
>
> A negative arc index indicates that the arc at the ones’ complement of
> the index must be reversed to reconstruct the geometry: -1 refers to
> the reversed first arc, -2 refers to the reversed second arc, and so
> on. In JavaScript, you can negate a negative arc index i using the
> bitwise NOT operator, ~i. ([docs](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-specification#214-arc-indexes))

Instead of `-0` you should be using `-1`. So your 2nd topojson example should draw as follows:

```
{"type":"Topology", 
        "crs":{"type":"name","properties": {"name":"EPSG:25832"}},
        "objects":{
        "collection": { "type": "GeometryCollection", 
             "geometries":[
                   { "type": "MultiPolygon", 
                     "arcs": [[[-1,-2]]],
                     "properties":{"id":9005309}}]}},
        "arcs":[
              [[565545.69,7786859.81],[565546,7786890.97]],
              [[565546,7786890.97],[565545.06,7786876.95],[565545.69,7786859.81]]
        ]
}
```